# Need some help with this recurrence equation

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I'm self studying from a book I bought to learn more about algorithms and I've been trying most of the exercises in that book, so this is not a homework. Anyways, the relation I'm trying to solve is 
$$
T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/4)+T(n/8)+n
$$

I need to find a good asymptotic upper and lower bounds.

So, far what I've done is to transform the above considering $n=2^m$ then

$$
T(2^m)=T(2^{m-1})+T(2^{m-2})+T(2^{m-3})+2^m
$$

then for $S(m)=T(2^m)$

$$
S(m)=S(m-1)+S(m-2)+S(m-3)+2^m
$$

using the recursion tree with this later equation is a lot easier but I'm still not able to get to the solution.

Hope I'm on the right path :)

Comment: put $ n\rightarrow n/2$ and then use both to get $T_n$ in terms of $T_{n/2}$

Comment: See if I understood this right. By considering n as some $m/2$ the first equation is transformed to $T(m/2)=T(m/4)+T(m/8)+T(m/16)+m/2$. But isn't this just on the second level of the tree?

Comment: No you can't use m/2 , use n/2 and then get $T_n=2T_{n/2}-n/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the recurrence should use $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ instead of $\frac{n}{2}$ (or ceiling, depending on the context), so that it is properly defined. It will look like this:

$$T(n)=T\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor \right)+T\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right \rfloor \right)+T\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{8} \right \rfloor \right)+n$$

Typically, when analysing asymptotic behaviour, we can ignore the floors. (which gives $O(1)$ error) We extend $T(n)$ to $[0, \infty)$ with $T(n)=T(\lfloor n \rfloor)$. We now get back the equation you have:

$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+n$$

Now, I shall show that $T(n)=8n+O(n^\theta)$, where $\theta \approx 0.87915$ is the only real root of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{\theta}-1=0$.

Indeed, if we subtract $8n$ from both sides of the above equation, we get:

$$(T(n)-8n)=(T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-\frac{8n}{2})+(T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)-\frac{8n}{4})+(T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)-\frac{8n}{8})$$

If we let $U(n)=T(n)-8n$, then

$$U(n)=U\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+U\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+U\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)$$

Suppose that for $1 \leq n \leq 8$, we have $an^{\theta} \leq U(n) \leq bn^{\theta}$, for some constants $a, b$. Indeed, we have

$$\min_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-64 \leq U(n)=T(n)-8n \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-8$$

If we let $a=\min(0, \min_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-64), b=\max(0, \max_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-8)$, then $an^{\theta} \leq a \leq U(n) \leq b \leq bn^{\theta}$.

It is now easy to prove by induction on $k$ that $an^{\theta} \leq U(n) \leq bn^{\theta} \, \forall n \in [2^k, 2^{k+1}]$. When $k=0, 1, 2$, the statement is trivial. Suppose that it holds for $1 \leq k \leq i, i \geq 2$. Consider $n \in [2^{i+1}, 2^{i+2}]$, then

\begin{align}
an^{\theta}& =a(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)^{\theta}) \\
& \leq U(n) \\
& =U\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+U\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+U\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) \\
& \leq b(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^{\theta}+\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)^{\theta}) \\
&=bn^{\theta}
\end{align}

We are thus done by induction.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. There's something that I'm still not seeing. This part  $$\min_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-64 \leq U(n)=T(n)-8n \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}-8$$  Maybe you can clarify that for me. Thanks

Comment: @user990692 That inequality is only for $1 \leq n \leq 8$. Basically, what I am doing is finding $a, b$ s.t. $an^{\theta} \leq U(n) \leq bn^{\theta}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 8$, so that I can extend this to all $n$ by induction. When $1 \leq n \leq 8$, we have $U(n)=T(n)-8n$, $-64=-8(8) \leq -8n \leq -8(1)=-8$ and $$\min_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)} \leq T(n) \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq 8, i \in \mathbb{Z}}{T(i)}$$ Combining gives that inequality **for $n$ between $1$ and $8$**.

Comment: Sorry, I got home here today and there are a couple of things that I'm still not getting. If $T(n)=8n+O(n^\theta)$ like you said that means that $T(n)=O(n)$ since $\theta < 1$. I wrote a program to display the values of $T(n)$ using as a base $T(0)=0, T(1)=1, T(2)=1$ and the growth of course if exponential, just like happens with Fibonacci numbers. If so, how can $T(n)=8n+O(n^\theta)=O(n)$?

Comment: @user990692 It should not be exponential. The recurrence for Fibonaacci relates $F_n$ to $F_{n-1}$ and $F_{n-2}$. This is in contrast to the recurrence for $T(n)$, which relates it to $\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{4}, \frac{n}{8}$. That equality you mention above is correct, because I defined $\theta$ to be the root of the equation $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\theta} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{\theta} + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{\theta} =1$$

Comment: You're right. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

We let the binary representation of $n$ be
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k$$
and assume for the base case that $T(0)=0$ and for the recursive step
$$ T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor)+T(\lfloor n/8 \rfloor)+n.$$

Then the value of $T(n)$ for all $n$ is given by
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3}
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k.$$
This formula is exact for all $n.$

Now let $\rho_{1,2,3}$ be the roots of $1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3 = 0,$ 
with $\rho_1$ the real root. Introduce
$$ \rho =\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}$$
Then we have
$$\rho_1 = \frac{2}{3} \rho - \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\rho} -\frac{2}{3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\rho_{2,3} = -\frac{1}{3} \rho + \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{\rho}
-\frac{2}{3}
\pm i \sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1}{3} \rho + \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{\rho}\right).$$
This yields
$$[z^j]  \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3}\\ =
\frac{8\rho_1^{-j-1}}{(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}+
\frac{8\rho_2^{-j-1}}{(\rho_2-\rho_1)(\rho_2-\rho_3)}+
\frac{8\rho_3^{-j-1}}{(\rho_3-\rho_1)(\rho_3-\rho_2)}.
$$
The numeric values of the inverses of the roots are
$$\frac{1}{\rho_1} \sim 0.9196433771
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{\rho_{2,3}} \sim -0.2098216888 \mp 0.3031453647 i.$$

Note that $1/\rho_1$ is real and that $1/\rho_{2,3}$ has the following modulus:
$$ \left|\frac{1}{\rho_{2,3}}\right| = 0.3686763530.$$
This implies that the contribution from $1/\rho_1$ dominates asymptotically.
To see this, simply note that
$$\frac{|(1/\rho_{2,3})^j|}{|(1/\rho_1)^j|} =
\frac{|1/\rho_{2,3}|^j}{|1/\rho_1|^j}
\rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as}\quad j \rightarrow \infty.$$

What we  have done here  is really nothing  more than apply  the known
rule that  the radius  of convergence of  a Taylor series  centered at
zero is  the distance  to the nearest  singularity, with  the dominant
asymptotics  of the coefficients  being contributed  by powers  of the
inverse of the modulus of that singularity.

We are  now ready  to check the  bounds, restricting ourselves  to the
contribution from  $1/\rho_1.$ The case  of a lower bound  occurs when
$n$ consists of a single one, followed by zeros, giving

$$ T(n) \ge 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3} \\ \sim
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
\frac{8}{\rho_1 (\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \rho_1^{-j}$$
or
$$\frac{8\times 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} }{\rho_1 (\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}
\frac{1-1/\rho_1^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{1-1/\rho_1}\\=
\frac{8\times 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} (1-1/\rho_1^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}) }
{(\rho_1-1) (\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}.$$

Now let
$$ 
P(n) = \frac{8\times 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}
{(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
Q(n) = \frac{8\times (2/\rho_1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}
{(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)},$$
so that the lower bound becomes
$$\frac{P(n)}{\rho_1-1} - \frac{Q(n)}{\rho_1(\rho_1-1)}.$$

The case of the upper bound occurs when $n$ is string of one digits, giving
$$T(n) \le \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3}
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^k \\=
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z -\frac{1}{4}z^2 -\frac{1}{8}z^3}
(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1} - 2^j)$$

The first part  of the difference is twice the  term we calculated for
the lower bound. The second part is

$$- \frac{8}{\rho_1 (\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} (2/\rho_1)^j =
- \frac{8}{\rho_1 (\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)} 
\frac{(2/\rho_1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}-1}{2/\rho_1-1}$$
or
$$- \frac{8\times (2/\rho_1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}-1}
{(2-\rho_1)(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)} =
- \frac{2 Q(n)}{\rho_1(2-\rho_1)} +  
\frac{1}{(2-\rho_1)(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}
$$

It follows that the upper bound is
$$ 2\frac{P(n)}{\rho_1-1} 
- 2 Q(n) \left(\frac{1}{\rho_1(\rho_1-1)} + \frac{1}{\rho_1(2-\rho_1)}\right) 
+ \frac{1}{(2-\rho_1)(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}.$$

Putting the upper and the lower bound together and observing that we have
$$P(n) \in \Theta(n)\quad\text{and}\quad
  Q(n) \in \Theta\left((2/\rho_1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta(n/2^{\log_2\rho_1 \log_2 n})
= \Theta(n^{1-\log_2\rho_1})$$

so that $$T(n) \in \Theta(n)$$ and the next term in the asymptotic expansion is
$\Theta(n^{1-\log_2\rho_1})$.

Taking certain liberties with the precise meaning of asymptotic expansions, we have
$$ T(n) \sim n 
- n^{1 - \log_2
\left(\frac{2}{3}\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}  
- \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}} -\frac{2}{3}\right)}.$$ 
(The exact coefficients on these terms are calculated above.)

Comment: There is another example of the use of this method at this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320927/unorthodox-solution-of-a-special-case-of-the-master-theorem).