# Simplify a recursively defined function in Maple

Tags: recurrence-relations, maple

I have the following problem. Out of the runtime analysis of an divide and conquer algorithm I got the following formula for the necessary flops:

```
flops(n): = (89+1/3)*n^3 + 2 * flops(n/2)
```

and

```
flops(1):= 0
```

I want to sum it up and to remove the recursion with Maple. But I do not get it working. Everytime Maple complains: *Error, (in flops) too many levels of recursion*

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can actually do a little more and find an exact solution to this recurrence. First solve for $S(n)$ where $S(0)=0$ and $$S(n) = 268/3 n^3 + 2 S(\lfloor n/2\rfloor).$$

Let $$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k$$ be the binary representation of $n.$
By inspection we see that
$$ S(n) = 268/3 \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^j
\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}  d_k 2^{k-j}\right)^3.$$
This formula is exact.

We are interested in $T(n)$ which has the same recurrence as $S(n)$ but with $T(1)=0.$ (We have $S(1)=268/3.$) So this gives
$$T(n) = -268/3 \times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} + 268/3 \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^j
\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}  d_k 2^{k-j}\right)^3.$$ This formula is exact, too.

To do the asymptotics we need upper and lower bounds. An upper bound occurs for a string of one digits, giving
$$T(n) \le 
268/3 \left(32/3\times 2^{3\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} -24\times 2^{2\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
+ 37/3 \times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} + 
6\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} +1\right).$$
We get the lower bound by considering a one followed by a string of zeros, giving
$$T(n) \ge 268/3
\left(4/3 \times 2^{3\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 
- 4/3 \times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}.\right).$$ 
If we put $m = 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}$ this becomes
$$ 268/3
\left(4/3 \times m^3 - 4/3 \times m\right) =
1072/9 \; m \; (m^2-1),$$
which is the result that acer computed in his post. 
The asymptotically dominant terms are
$$ 268/3 \times 32/3\times 2^{3\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \quad \text{and} \quad
268/3 \times 4/3 \times 2^{3\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor},$$
so that $$T(n) \in \Theta\left(2^{3\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}\right) =
\Theta\left(2^{3\log_2 n}\right) = \Theta(n^3),$$
in accordance with the Master theorem.

Comment: There is more material on this method [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320927/unorthodox-solution-of-a-special-case-of-the-master-theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Are you intending that `n` and integer and a power of 2?

```
restart:

Flops:=proc(N::rational)
   if N<=1 then return 0;
   else (89+1/3)*N^3+2*procname(N/2);
   end if;
end proc:

seq(Flops(2^i), i=0..4);

           0, 2144/3, 21440/3, 60032, 1457920/3

G:=unapply(rsolve({flops(n)=(89+1/3)*n^3+2*flops(n/2),flops(1)=0},
                  flops),
           n);

                                           2
                      G := n -> 1072/9 n (n  - 1)

seq(G(2^i), i=0..4);                                                

           0, 2144/3, 21440/3, 60032, 1457920/3
```

Comment: The G is the one I am searching for, thanks.