# Verify if T(n) = T(n/2) + log(n) - Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but could you please verify if this is right:

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + log_{2}(n)\\
T(n) &= T\left(\frac{n}{2^{i}}\right) + n\sum_{i-1}^{k=0} \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{i}\\    
T(n) &= 1 + n\left[2 - \frac{1}{2^{log(n)-1}}\right]    \\
T(n) &= 2n - 1\\
\end{align}$$

I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: man forget about 4 spaces, you are _so_ close to latex nirvana, you should put those double dollars in and achieve equation enlightenment :)

Comment: this looks a lot like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689108/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-tn-2tn-2n-log-n#comment1444949_689108

Answer (score 1):

No - for example if $$T(4)=2 \times 4-1=7$$ then $$T(8)=T(4)+\log_2(8)= 7+3=10 \not = 2 \times 8-1.$$

Just looking at powers of 2:

$$T(2)=T(1)+1$$
$$T(4)=T(2)+2=T(1)+3$$
$$T(8)=T(4)+3=T(1)+6$$
$$T(2^n)=T(1)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: is the second line of my equations correct? I had a different answer of T(n) = log^2(n) previously

Comment: No it is not.  See my addition