# Calculate a recursive equation in terms of theta

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am struggling with the following equation for one week!
Please help me solve it.

$$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{2})+\frac{n}{logn}$$

So far, I have come to the equation $T(n)=\Sigma \frac{2^x}{x}$

Comment: What is theta, what is x, what are the summation limits in T(n)?

Answer (score 1):

Using Master theorem, you can choose $c=\frac{1}{2}>0=log_21$, and you get: $f(n)=\frac{n}{logn}=\Omega(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$. In this case the theorem would yield: $T(n)=\Theta(\frac{n}{logn})$.

Comment: Doesn't $c$ equal to 0?

Comment: We are using "case 3" of the Master theorem and so we are free to choose a c which is greater than log_a(b)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $T(0)=0$ and $T(1) = 1$ and your recurrence for $n>1$ is
$$T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + \frac{n}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}.$$
By unrolling the recursion we find the **exact** formula for $n\ge 2:$
$$T(n) = 1 + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - k}
\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} d_j 2^{j-k}$$
where the digits $d_j$ are from the binary representation of $n$ given by
$$n = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} d_j 2^j.$$ 
We now compute upper and lower bounds. For an upper bound consider a string of one digits, which gives
$$T(n)\le 1 + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - k}
\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} 2^{j-k}
=  1 + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - k}
\left(2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1-k} -1\right)
\\ = 1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1}
\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1-k}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - k}
= 1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} + 
2\times \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}\frac{2^k}{k}.$$
To extract the asymptotics from this we use the next-to-last form, which gives
$$1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} + 
\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1}
\frac{2^{-k}}{1 - \frac{k}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}}
\\ = 1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} + 
\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} 2^{-k}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{k 2^{-k}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{k^2 2^{-k}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^2}
+\cdots\right)
\\= 1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} \\+ 
\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} 2^{-k}
+ \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1}k 2^{-k}
+ \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} k^2 2^{-k}
+\cdots\right).$$
The sums all converge to numbers so we finally get
$$1 - H_{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} + 
\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\left(2
+ \frac{2}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
+ \frac{6}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^2}
+ \frac{26}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^3}
+\cdots\right).$$
Continuing with the lower bound which occurs for a one digit followed by a string of zeroes we get
$$T(n)\ge 1 + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} \frac{1}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - k}
2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor-k}
= 1 + 
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor} \frac{2^k}{k}.$$
To extract the asymptotics we work with the next-to-last form, which gives
$$1 + \frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor - 1} 
\frac{2^{-k}}{1 - \frac{k}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}}.$$
The sum is the same as before so we finally have the lower bound
$$1 + \frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
\left(2
+ \frac{2}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}
+ \frac{6}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^2}
+ \frac{26}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor^3}
+\cdots\right).$$
Note that these bounds are attained. Joining the upper and the lower bound we have a complexity of
$$T(n)\in\Theta\left(\frac{2^{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}}{\lfloor\log_2 n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$$
which to be clear about it could have been spotted by inspection, but there is no harm in doing a formal proof.

**Remark.** The reader may profit from studying the calculation at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689108/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-tn-2tn-2n-log-n) which is similar but just different enough to create a learner's effect. (Unfortunately it has $j$ and $k$ in the explicit formula reversed but this does not warrant editing everything I have just written.)

**Observation.** When using the asymptotic expansion for fixed $n$ care must be taken because the coefficients eventually outgrow the inverse powers of the logarithm. The best value to use is the one just before the expansion starts diverging.

**Addendum.** The sequence of coefficients $2,2,6,26,\ldots$ in the asymptotic expansion is examined in detail at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710064/showing-that-2f-11-n-1n2-frac12-in-o2n).