# Why is $a^nb^n|n\geq1$ not regular and $a^nb^n|n\leq {10^{10}}$ regular?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, regular-expressions

I've heard somewhere that since the latter is bounded, it is regular. Can anyone explain me what a **bound** actually means? 
And if the latter is regular, then how would you write the **regular expression** for it?

Comment: The title and the question seem to contradict each other. Is your title the wrong way around?

Comment: Bounded here means **finite**. Each finite language is regular. The regular expression is simply $w_1 + w_2 +\dots + w_n$, where $(w_m)_{m=1,\dots,n}$ is an enumeration for the language.

Comment: @TonyK my mistake, corrected.

Comment: Of course, in this case, there are $10^{10}$ cases, so the resulting regular expression would be rather long...

Comment: What is happening [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074827/)?