# Master Theorem for solving recurrences question

Tags: recurrence-relations

Who can explain to me why
$$T (n) = 4T (n/2) + n/ \log n \Longrightarrow T (n) = Θ(n^2) \tag{Case 1}$$

But for
$$T (n) = 2T (n/2) + n/ \log n$$ ⇒ Master Theorem does not apply (non-polynomial difference between $f(n) = n^{\log_ba}$)

Comment: A Google search for "Master theorem" brings up links like this http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.1636

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689108/) solves the above recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see  $O(n^2)$ is at least $n$ times bigger than $O(\frac{n}{logn})$ so we can say there is a polynomial difference ( a difference measured in $n^k$).

For the second it doesn't apply because its $O(n)$ and $O(n/logn)$ the difference is not $n^k$. The difference is only $logn$ but master theorem apply only for polynomial, the difference here is not polynomial but logarithmic

Comment: Can you pls give more details? it is not fully clear to me.... 
(n/logn)/n^2 = 1/nlogn
(n/logn)/n = 1/logn

so... what should I get from this?