# Master theorem for recurrence analysis

Tags: computational-complexity, data-structure

The master method - why can't it solve $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + \frac{n}{\log n}.$

What's the issue with the master theorem?
Why is there like different concepts on different channels?
What formula applies?
what is "polynomial check"?
when does the k method apply?
There are so many questions in which some say master theorem cannot be applied but some give out the answers.

I m pretty confused right now - what to follow?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange also from me. Maybe, this helps : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't this be done with Master Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597931/why-cant-this-be-done-with-master-theorem)