# $T(n) = 2T(\frac n 2) +\frac n {\log n}$ and the master theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I tried to use the master theorem to solve $T(n) = 2T(\frac n 2) +\frac n {\log n}$, and I got $\frac n {\log n} \overset{?} = O(n^{1-\epsilon})$, now it looks like it should work:

$\frac n {\log n} \le cn\Rightarrow 1 \le c \log n$ which is true for every $c$, so from the master thorem $T(n)=\Theta (n)$, but I see in my notes that's it's actually not, but why?

Comment: Let $G(n)=T(n)/n$. Then $G(n)=G(n/2)+\frac 1 {\log n}$ which yields $G(n)\sim H_{\log n}\sim\log\log n$, hence $T(n)\sim n\log\log n\ne \Theta(n)$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes I know how to solve it in other ways, but why does the master theorem fails here?

Comment: Because the recurrence doesn't satisfy any of its 3 cases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Inadmissible_equations. You need to use a more general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method instead.

Comment: I see, thank you. @A.S.

Comment: Several different approaches to this recurrence appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689108/).