# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{2}\log(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Please help me solve the recurrence

$$ T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{2}\log(n) $$

Comment: I have tried substituting with 2^m, but kind of getting lost towards the end. Just wanted to verify if it is O(nlogn) or O(n(logn)^2)

Comment: $\frac{n}{4}\big(\log n (\log_2\!n + 1) + \text{const.}\big)$ is one possible solution of the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exact solution of a related recurrence that has the same complexity as yours. We take $T(0)=0$ and the recurrence is
$$T(n) = 2 T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + \frac{1}{2} n \; (\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor+1).$$
Let the binary digits of $n$ be given by
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k.$$
Then the **exact** solution to the recurrence is
$$T(n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^k
(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +1 - k)\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_j 2^{j-k}.$$
Now an upper bound on $T(n)$ is given by the case where we have a string of ones, producing
$$T(n) \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^k
(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +1 - k)\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^{j-k}
\\= \frac{1}{2}\times
\left(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor^2 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
+ 3 \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
- 2 \times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} + \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +3\right).$$
We get a lower bound when $n$ is a one digit followed by zeros, giving
$$T(n)\ge \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} 2^k
(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +1 - k) 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor-k}
= \frac{1}{2}\times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
(\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +1 - k)
\\ = \frac{1}{2}\times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
\left(\frac{1}{2} \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor^2
+\frac{3}{2} \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor +1\right).$$
Taking the two dominant terms from the upper and lower bound we get the asymptotic complexity as
$$\Theta\left( \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor^2 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}\right)
= \Theta(\log^2 n\times n).$$

This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505004/how-to-find-a-closed-form-solution-to-a-recurrence-of-the-following-form) points to a series of similar calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem):

Using the master theorem's notation, we have $a = 2$; $b = 2$; $c = \log_b{a} = 1$; $f(n) = \frac{n}{2}\log(n)$.

This corresponds to the master theorem's case 2, where: $f(n) = \Theta\left( n^{c} \log^{k} n \right)$, which implies $T(n) = \Theta\left( n^{c} \log^{k+1} n \right)$.

Replacing with our values, we get:
$T(n) = \Theta\left( n^1 \log^{1+1} n \right) = \Theta\left( n \log^{2} n \right)$